# Intermittant file not found using Google Cloud Storage from Dataproc - flushing writes?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a series of dataproc jobs that run to import some data received each morning. The process creates a cluster, runs four jobs in sequence, then shuts down the cluster. The input file is read from Google Cloud Storage, and the intermediate results are also saved in Avro form in GCS with the final output going to Cloud SQL.

Fairly often the jobs will fail trying to read the Avro written by the previous job. It appears that GCS hasn't "caught up" and the results from the previous job haven't been fully written. I was getting failures trying to read files that appeared to be from the previous day's run and partway through those files would disappear and be replaced by the new ones. I have changed my script that runs the files to clear the work area before starting the jobs, but still have problems where sometimes it starts reading and all the parts haven't been written fully.

I could change the code to simply store the intermediate files on the cluster, tho I like having them available outside for diagnosing other problems. I could also just write to both locations with the cluster for working and GCS for diagnostics.

But assuming this is some kind of sync issue, is there a way to force GCS to flush writes / be fully synced between jobs? Or is there some check I can do to make sure everything has been written before starting the next job in my chain?

EDIT: To answer the comment below, the sequence of jobs all run on the same cluster. The cluster is started, each job run in turn on that cluster, and then the cluster is shut down.

For now, I have worked around this by having the jobs write to HDFS on the cluster in addition to GCS, and the subsequent jobs reading from the cluster. The GCS output is now strictly for diagnostics in case of a problem. But even tho my immediate problem is (I believe) fixed I still would like to know what's happening and why GCS seems out of sync for a bit.

Comment: One important distinction: do the failures ever happen when the previous job ran in the exact same cluster as the subsequent job? Or does it only happen when the previous job ran on a different/old cluster?

Comment: Though GCS normally has [eventual list consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency), Dataproc clusters by default come equipped with a client-side mechanism for enforcing same-cluster immediate list consistency. Please contact us at dataproc-feedback@google.com with your project ID so that we can verify whether the job is doing something incompatible with the list consistency mechanism and/or whether there are project settings which are causing the problems you see.